# ASP.Net MVC View с хелпером @Html.React не загружает весь bundle упакованный webpack-ом

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, npm, webpack4

Имеется VS2017 v.15.9.5. Создаю проект MVC Core 2.2. Добавляю nuget-пакеты React.AspNet 4.0 и ChakraCore. И после стандартных действий, что описаны ниже, сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой: при размещении на любой вьюшке хелпера @Html.React с любым реакт-компонентом эта страница сразу перестает цеплять весь bundle index.js, упакованный webpack-ом, а все остальные страницы работают нормально.

Итак, по порядку: в Startup.cs добавлено все, как в [мануалах](https://reactjs.net/):

```js
В   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services):
services.AddReact();
services.AddJsEngineSwitcher(options => options.DefaultEngineName=ChakraCoreJsEngine.EngineName).AddChakraCore();

В   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env):
config.SetLoadBabel(false).AddScriptWithoutTransform("~/wwwroot/bundle/index.js");
```

Далее инициализирую npm и ставлю следующие пакеты:

```js
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.5",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.9.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0-1",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^5.3.3",
    "webpack": "^4.29.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.2.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "jquery-validation": "^1.19.0",
    "jquery-validation-unobtrusive": "^3.2.9",
    "popper.js": "^1.9.9",
    "react": "^16.7.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
    "react-modal": "^3.8.1",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4"
  }
```

И создаю тестовый HelloWorld компонент в wwwroot/scripts/index.jsx

```js
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "../css/site.css";
import "../../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js";
import "../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js";
import "../../node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js";
import "../../node_modules/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/dist/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"
import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js";
import "../../node_modules/react/umd/react.development.js";
import "../../node_modules/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js";
import "../../node_modules/react-modal/dist/react-modal.js";

class Hello extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="testDiv">
                <h1>Привет, React.JS</h1>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

На всякий случай приведу еще webpack.config.js:

```js
const webpack = require("webpack");
let path = require('path');
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const bundleFolder = 'wwwroot/bundle/';
module.exports = {
    entry: './wwwroot/scripts/index.jsx',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: "babel-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                exclude: [/node_modules/],
                loader: "json-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(scss)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'style-loader', 
                }, {
                    loader: 'css-loader', 
                }, {
                    loader: 'postcss-loader', 
                    options: {
                        plugins: function () { 
                            return [
                                require('precss'),
                                require('autoprefixer')
                            ];
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    loader: 'sass-loader' 
                }]
            },
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".jsx", ".json", ".tsx", ".css", ".ts"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'index.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'wwwroot/bundle'),
    },
    plugins: ([
        new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            Popper: ['popper.js', 'default'], 
        }),
        new CleanWebpackPlugin([bundleFolder],
            {
                "verbose": true 
            })
    ]),
    stats: {
        colors: true,
        modules: true,
        reasons: true,
        errorDetails: true

    }
}
```

Выполняем npm run build успешно, index.js создается в папке wwwroot/bundle. 
В _Layout.cshtml указываю

```js
 <script src="~/bundle/index.js"></script>
@RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
```

А далее начинаются чудеса, в любую вьюшку вставляю

```
@Html.React("Hello ", new { name = "Test" })
```

и она после сборки и запуска в браузере перестает подхватывать `~/bundle/index.js`, и соответственно ни bootstrap ни react не работают. Как только удаляю хелпер @Html.React, сразу все ок: и index.js цепляется и bootstrap со стилями.

Comment: Ошибки в консоли есть?

Comment: при сборке npm никаких шибок - только warnings про mode options has not been seet, что размер бандла 782 кб и может быть снижение производительности.  Есть подозрение, что проблема в некоем дублировании\конфликте реакта из nuget-пакета и импорте реакт-библиотек в jsx-файле